# Should I use the Guidelines Support Library (GSL) in a new C++ project?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

What are the pros and cons in favor of and against using the Guidelines Support Library (GSL) in a new C++ project? I find some constructs there very attractive but am a bit scared of including and relying on such a fundamental library.

Comment: It is pretty much useless unless they properly implement checked iterators...

Comment: this is either too broad or opinion based. Its a library like any other, use it when you think it helps, dont if you dont like the dependency

Comment: Would you rather I re-phrased the question as "What are the pros and cons of using GSL?".

Comment: not sure, i voted to close but at the same time i think it is an interesting question. Sometimes its just a matter of wording, maybe "Can I use the GSL when I dont strictly follow the guidelines or vice versa?" is a bit more objective while leading to the same answer

Answer (score 3):

The GSL is just a support library for the C++ core guidelines. If you are using the GSL, then these core guidelines should be the guidelines you apply to your code (not Google's or any other found online). You don't need the GSL for the core guidelines nor do you need to use everything in the GSL. Personnally I have started using it for simple bits like `index` and `not_null`.

The GSL is not perfect, there are many things that could/should be added, it doesn't impede me for doing crazy things, but it helps adding a framework/some kind of verification to what I'm doing. Also it removes the signed/unsigned issues with `index`.

I would advise to use it in a new project, as its run-time overhead should be null, but it's a matter of taste. If your project has lots of new developers (or toddlers), then it's something considering to help them growing up.

Comment: how does GSL relate to eg boost? Is it to be expected that GSL stuff will make it into the standard library at some point?

Comment: I hope `gsl::index` does, and I think there are a few bits that are also reasonnable enough, like `not_null`. `span` is already on the path to inclusion (AFAIK).

Comment: actually thats something I would consider as argument against using it, tough I just learned that it is header only with is again a strong argument to use it... I think time will tell how it will evolve

Comment: The fact that things are going inside the language? After, it's just a matter of replacing the namespace, not a big deal. But in general, it's far lighter than Boost in terms of usage, it's just for support, not for fundamental stuff.

Comment: i just meant that if eventually it goes into the standard then my motivation is less to consider it now unless i urgently need it, but maybe i should take a closer look before making such unqualified statements ;)